# MongoDB : Unable to drop a Compound Index on a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a compound index on my collection called **people** as shown below

```
 db.people.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "at.people",
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("521dd652a185d3defe301983"),
                "ns" : "at.people",
                "key" : {
                        "personname" : 1,
                        "email" : 1,
                        "sex" : 1,
                        "course" : 1
                },
                "name" : "personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1",
                "unique" : false
        }
]
```

I am trying to drop this index this way

```
 db.people.dropIndex({"personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1": 1})
```

But i am getting error message as

{ "errmsg" : "index not found", "ok" : 0 }

I also tried to drop the index by name

```
db.people.dropIndex( { "name" : "personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1" } )
```

I know i can drop the indexes on a collection in one shot using the below command

```
db.people.dropIndexes()
```

Please let me know how to resolve this ?

Comment: You should drop it this way: `db.people.dropIndex({personname:1,email:1,sex:1,course:1})`

Comment: Thanks , will this above command dropother individual indexes which are on that field ?? for example i have a individual  index as db.people.ensureIndex({"personname" : 1}, {"unique" : false})

Comment: No, will drop only that one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass the index name into `dropIndex` without putting it into an object:

```
db.people.dropIndex("personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1")
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to make full answer.

From documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/ you should use `db.collection.dropIndex()` with `string or document` that:

> Specifies the index to drop. You can specify the index either by the
>   index name or by the index specification document.

So both:

```
db.people.dropIndex("personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1")
db.people.dropIndex({personname:1,email:1,sex:1,course:1})
```

works fine.

Comment: Yep the 2nd one worked for me. The 1st wasn't working for me - might've been due to a weird index name or the fact we had 2 indexes with the same name lol

Answer (score 1):

I think you are very close. Modifying your command to the below one should work

```
db.people.dropIndex("personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1")
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop mongodb index

```
    Syntax :  db.collection.dropIndex(index)
```

> Here,
>
> > index    :   Type : string or document
>
> Specifies the index to drop. You can specify the index either by the
>   index name or by the index specification document To drop a text
>   index, specify the index name as type string

In yout case :

```
db.people.dropIndex("personname_1_email_1_sex_1_course_1")
```

**To under in more details :**
Consider a pets collection. Calling the getIndexes() method on the pets collection returns the following indexes:

```
[
   {  "v" : 1,
      "key" : { "_id" : 1 },
      "ns" : "test.pets",
      "name" : "_id_"
   },
   {
      "v" : 1,
      "key" : { "cat" : -1 },
      "ns" : "test.pets",
      "name" : "catIdx"
   },
   {
      "v" : 1,
      "key" : { "cat" : 1, "dog" : -1 },
      "ns" : "test.pets",
      "name" : "cat_1_dog_-1"
   }
]
```

The single field index on the field cat has the user-specified name of catIdx and the index specification document of { "cat" : -1 }.

To drop the index catIdx, you can use either the index name:

```
db.pets.dropIndex( "catIdx" )
```

Or you can use the index specification document { "cat" : -1 }:

```
db.pets.dropIndex( { "cat" : -1 } )
```

Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#index-name